# How to update Kendo UI LinearGauge's ranges to-value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

At the moment, I have a linear gauge looking like this:

```
$("#depthBar-" + conveyanceId).kendoLinearGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: 0,
        shape: "arrow",
        color: "transparent",
        start: 0,
        reverse: true
    },
    scale: {
        majorUnit: 500,
        minorUnit: 100,
        min: -2000,
        max: 2000,
        vertical: false,
        reverse: false,
        ranges: [
            {
                from: -2000, // LimitLo
                to: -1500,
                color: "#ffc700"
            },
            {
                from: 2000, // LimitHi
                to: 1500,
                color: "#ffc700"
            }, {
                from: 2000, // LimitHiHi
                to: 1800,
                color: "#c20000"
            }, {
                from: -5000,
                to: -1800,
                color: "#c20000" // LimitLoLo
            }, {
                from: 0,
                to: 286,
                color: "lightblue"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically update the "to" value of the last range (the one using lightblue as color). But, I can't seem to figure out how to update that property. This is how I'm currently looking up the property:

```
$('#depthBar-' + conveyanceId).data("kendoLinearGauge").options.scale.ranges[4].to = newVal;
```

However, this does not seem to do the trick. If I assign the whole statement to a tmp variable and inspect it in Chrome debugger I get the correct range I'm looking for. Just not able to set the "to" property with a new value. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
 $('#depthBar-' + conveyanceId).data("kendoLinearGauge").options.scale.ranges[4].to = depthMessage;
 $('#depthBar-' + conveyanceId).data("kendoLinearGauge").redraw();
```